# Estimote Beacons & Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ibeacon, estimote

How does one use an Estimote Beacon in a Xamarin Forms project? After scouring the vast expanse of the internet I have yet to find a straight answer. I have tried translating Estimote's Java documentation into C# but that didn't work. I've also tried using the SDK to create my own solution but that did not work as well. I feel like this should be simple:

```
var beaconManager = new BeaconManager();
var region = new BeaconRegion("region info");

beaconManager.StartListening(region);

beaconManager.RegionEntered += (s, e) => {
   //Some Logic
}
```

Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is a step by step blog about using it. https://blog.estimote.com/post/104250171600/building-an-estimote-scavenger-hunt-on-ios Here is a video about how to use with iBeacon and Eddystone https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Xamarin-Evolve/2016/Clicking-on-the-Real-World-with-iBeacon-and-Eddystone.

Comment: This might help: https://allancritchie.net/posts/shiny-beacons